# Why does my app keep crashing on startup - Android

Tags: java, android, crash

Just followed a youtube guide on how to make a button and an activity. I followed his code down to the font size and it keeps on crashing when i start it. Anyone know why?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addButtonClickListner();
    }

    public void addButtonClickListner() {
        Button btnNavigator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.premierleague.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, this code does not compile, hence it cannot crash when you start it.

Comment: first thing you should define any views in onCreate method (you may declare them before onCreate). and why not post stacktrace or atleast details of what the error is rather than saying i have error.

Comment: @njzk2 he only has 25 points, cut him some slack. He probably doesn't know to use the stacktrace to debug yet, otherwise he would have posted it. A constructive comment would be "Post your stacktrace and other debug info so we can help :)" with a link to something that explains what a stacktrace is.

Comment: new or not, I think taking 2 minutes to read other question in order to have a sense of what it takes to obtain an answer seems a minimum, but maybe that's just me being picky.

Comment: It's common for new programmers to ask for help on StackOverflow without showing the steps they've taken to solve their problem. He's only asked a handful of questions so you should have _kindly_ told him to post more info and do more research.

Answer (score 0):

try to add http:// before the name of your site !

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW
>   Uri.parse("http://www.premierleague.com"));

and verify if you have really named the button correctly button1

i mean in your xml did you used something like :

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
```